# Service worker unexpected behavior with 2 react apps on same domain

Tags: reactjs, service-worker, create-react-app

I have 2 `react apps` (bootstrapped with [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app)) running on the same domain. One app is served on the root (`mydomain.com`) and the other is served inside a subfolder (`mydomain.com/path`). The bundles are served statically using nginx.

When I go to `mydomain.com`, the service worker for the root app is registered and on further visits loads the `index.html` from the cache. When I visit `mydomain.com/path/` the service worker for the second app is registered and on further visits loads the appropriate `index.html` from the cache.

The issue is that when I visit `mydomain.com/path` (**without a trailing slash**), the service worker for the app on the root loads its index.html, and basically overrides the service worker registered for the subfolder (`/path`). However, it works fine if I visit `mydomain.com/path/` (**with a trailing slash**), and the service worker for the subfolder takes charge.

I am not sure if that is the expected behavior of the service worker. If yes, how can I get it to work without having to use a trailing slash? (I already tried explicitly setting a scope while registering the service worker for the subfolder)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid this is an edge case that current browsers don't handle well.

However it's not difficult to modify the service-worker on the root path so that it is active only if the path is not `/path`.

```
if( !self.location.pathname.startsWith('/path') ) {
    // Do root service-worker stuff
}
```